# Finding Datatype mismatches or translations in Teradata queries

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I'm planning to analyse the queries where there are datatype mismatches or translations  (example: Numeric joining to Strings) occurring during joins or Filters.We have a lot of tables which users create for their own usage and I want to capture these as well and I expect to find a lot of them. Knowing it may not be straight forward, what would be a generic approach to capture these details ? Are there any DBC Tables which offer some way to extract these details ?

*Example Output :*
TableA.StoreNumber **(Integer)**   *was joined to* TableB.Location **(Varchar)**

Comment: For columns in tables, you can query DBC.ColumnsV for metadata. Unfortunately for columns in views the info would be NULL. You could use `SHOW COLUMN databasename.viewname.*` to retrieve view metadata, one view at a time. (This can also be used for tables, if desired.) You might also consider capturing EXPLAIN data and looking for generated cast to `FLOAT` or `TRANSLATE` to Unicode for comparison.

Comment: Once I get the column names, I can lookup DBC.ColumnsV, that is a given.Its finding the queries and columns within them which have had to be TRANSLATED or CAST which is the tough part. I thought about capturing explain plan, but we are talking about going through a hundred thousand queries per day & each query having multiple TRANSLATIONS. I wonder if Teradata captures/stores this info in a simpler format which can be decoded easily.

Comment: If enabled, QryLogObjectsV stores info about columns used for joins, but not which join exactly. QryLogExplainV stores the full explain text, extracting join columns could be done using RegEx. Easiest way will be QryLogXMLV, but it's usually not enabled, see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/i_VlYHwN0b8knh6AEWrv1Q/HqTgcF6p1K_XPzp6DTU13A

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. I will explore enabling the XML option. I realize that we will need a lot more space on DBC and PDCR to store these as I have to enable them for a lot of users due to my scope. Would you know if we should expect any performance (or any negative) impact  as a result of enabling XMLPLAN Capturing.

Comment: I don't think (but don't know) there's a performance impact. Applying compression on the XML-table in PDCR will help keeping its size low.